# How to substract number of days in PHP

Tags: php

I have to compute a specific date considering the number of days I want to substract.

My code looks roughly like this:

```
$datac = date("Y-m-d");
$data = strtotime("-1 day" ,$datac);
```

But the output is: -84384
I don't understand what I do wrong. 
It should work something like date -1 and show the date from yesterday. Thank you!

Comment: `$datac`needs to be a timestamp, not a formatted date.. You can find more information about `strtotime()` in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Because the second argument to [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) should be a unix timestamp, not a formatted date string

Answer (score 0):

```
$datac = new DateTime();
$datac->modify('-1 day');
$data = $datac->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$datac = date("Y-m-d");
$data = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-1 day' . $datac));
```